# How do I link android library (as Angle) to my Eclipse project?

Tags: java, android, static-libraries, angle

Nooby question, I guess, but.
I downloaded free android engine called Angle from [here](http://code.google.com/p/angle/downloads/list).
There is a source and an example. I imported this project to Eclipse and now getting errors:

```
Project 'ANGLE' is missing required source folder: 'gen'
```

and there was no such directory in package, so, I guess, I need to create it? In my helloWorld created without any libraries I have `R.java` in this folder (gen/com/companyName/appName/R.java).

Also, there was another error - project was for "android-3", and I have sdk beginning with 2.2 (android-8). So I changed target to android 2.2 and got an error

```
Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0.
Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
```

So, what are "android tools"? Never seen this option.

Thanks for any help. New to Eclipse, new to Android, so need some advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do mouse right click on your project and you will see "Android tools" in context menu.

Comment: Shoot me in a head. Thanks. It created needed R.java too. Magic.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your project and select Android Tools > Fix Project Properties 
If it's does'nt work, Right click on your project => properties and select an android sdk version. Clean the project and rebuild.

To convert the project to Library project, Right click => properties => Android => Is Library => OK

Answer (score 1):

Right click on project => Android Tools

also try to change compliler to 1.7

to connect library project : right click=> android => Add and choose library project